# Assembly Irvine x86 Encrypting and Decrypting with ASCII

Tags: assembly, encryption, x86, char, irvine32

I'm using x86 assembly and with it, I need to take a string of 20 chars, or more, and get a char from the user. Then I need to rotate each char by two bits and then `XOR` it with the ASCII code.

The problem is that I can get the user string and the char, but how would I loop through the string? I tried looping through it like an array, but then it just crashed.

```
.386
.model flat,stdcall
.stack 4096
  ExitProcess proto,dwExitCode:dword
  WriteDec PROTO
  WriteString PROTO
  WriteChar PROTO
  Crlf PROTO
  ReadString PROTO
  DumpRegs PROTO
  Delay PROTO
.data
  MAX = 80                        ;max chars to read, if we input more it just gets cut off
  stringIn BYTE MAX+1 DUP (?)     ;room for null
  stringASCII BYTE MAX+1 DUP (?)  ;room for null
  CharMAX = 2;
  storedString DWORD ?
  storedASCII  DWord ?
  savedSpots   Dword ?

  Command      byte  "Enter your 20 Word string"  ,0
  askforChar   byte  "Enter a char"  ,0
  Encrypt      byte  "Encrypted String"  ,0


.code
main PROC
  mov  edx , OFFSET Command     ;Enter your 20 word String
  call WriteString              ;print it
  call CRLF                     ;space
  mov  edx, OFFSET stringIn     ;get the address of where we are gonna put our response
  mov  ecx, MAX                 ;mov max value of chars
  call ReadString               ;read it
  call CRLF                     ;space

  mov  edx , OFFSET askforChar  ;Then ask for a single char
  call WriteString              ;write it out
  call CRLF                     ;clear the line
  mov  edx, OFFSET stringASCII  ;get the address of where we are gonna put our char
  mov  ecx, CharMAX             ;get the one ASCII code
  call ReadString               ;double space
  call CRLf                     ;double space

  mov  edx, OFFSET stringASCII  ;this was just a test to reprint our word
  mov  storedASCII, edx         ;
  mov  ecx, CharMAX             ;get the same max value
  call CRLF

  mov  edx , OFFSET Encrypt     ;Encrypted String
  call WriteString              ;print it
  call CRLF                     ;space
  mov  esi,OFFSET stringIN      ;get our string address
  mov  ecx, MAX                 ;get our counter
L1:
  mov  edx, [esi]
  call WriteChar
  call CRLF
  add  esi, TYPE stringIN
Loop L1;
  ret
main ENDP
end main
```

Edit: re-added Loop

Comment: _"I got rid of my Loop that tried to go through StringIn since it didn't work"_ Unless you post it we can't possibly say what you did wrong.

Comment: fair enough, I just figured it was flat out wrong due to the crash Hold on.

Comment: added the Loop back in. I thought it would have worked. Grab the address of where the StringIn begins, then derefrence it, put into edx, Print it, clear the line, add +1 to esi, since it's a byte, which would then grab the second char, and so on and so forth

Comment: `WriteString` doesn't expect a character though; it expects the address of a NUL-terminated string in `edx`.

Comment: Ahh, ok, so I changed that to WriteChar, which should get just the single value and it does print...but it prints a tiny box with a question mark inside?

Comment: I'm sorry, I messed up your edit by trying to format it. Please fix your updates for your question to be up to date. Our edits were intermixed by the system.

Comment: I fixed it, I re-added the Loop, with the writeChar change that Micheal pointed out.

Comment: `mov edx, [esi]` is incorrect, because 1) a character is a byte, not a doubleword, and 2) `WriteChar` [doesn't expect its parameter in `edx`](http://programming.msjc.edu/asm/help/source/irvinelib/writechar.htm).

Comment: I edited it one more time and I think this is (approximately) how it should be.

Comment: Thank you zx485, and right, I cant believe I forgot that the register was al, Ill make those changes and see what I can get.

Comment: Ok, so I got it printing the first char, it just prints H's right now, so all I have to do is figure out how to make it grab the other chars in the string and then I can start encrypting it. Thanks Micheal

Comment: Alright thanks Micheal I got it to print the entire string char by char. I can't assign you the answer through so if you want you can make  new post so I can give you the points